# Is there a way to fix xamarin error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry' to 'Microcharts.ChartEntry'

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, charts

I try to use Microcharts, but they are changed `using Entry = Microcharts.Entry;` to `using Entry = Microcharts.ChartEntry;`

When I use `using Entry = Microcharts.ChartEntry;` on my csharp code I receive many errors like this:

```
/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.6.8 Microcharts error/WeatherLocationInfo/MainPage.xaml.cs(160,160): Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry' to 'Microcharts.ChartEntry' (CS1503) (WeatherLocationInfo)
```

When I clicked on error I see this part of the code:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_cityEntry.Text))
        {
          ..... code.....
        }
```

How to make `_cityEntry.Text` part of Xamarin.Forms.Entry ?

Comment: Your `using` alias directive doesn't automatically make `Microcharts.ChartEntry` compatible with `Xamarin.Forms.Entry`. The alias is making things more difficult for you at this point, hiding type differences that matter. Just remove it and deal with the types by their actual names.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: Just read the documentation on how to use Microcharts. It's possible that you're trying to add a Microcharts `ChartEntry` to a Xamarin.Forms chart control. I don't use Xamarin so I'm just guessing on the specifics.

Comment: I already suggested in your previous question that you need to remove that line